# error while using google.golang.org/grpc from a vendor directory

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I am having issues using google.golang.org/grpc from vendor directory and I get the below error

```
cannot use &metadata.HeaderMD (type *"google.golang.org/grpc/metadata".MD) as type *"project1/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/metadata".MD in argument to grpc.Header
```

I get the error though I am using the necessary version of the package which I copied from my gopath. But, when I delete the golang.google.org/grpc folder from vendor my project fetches the dependency from gopath and it works fine though the one gopath is a copy of when I have in vendor directory and every other library in vendor directory works fine except grpc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created `project1/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc`, it means that for packages under `project1/...`, an import of `google.golang.org/gprc/...` will be transparently remapped to the vendor version.

Any packages outside of `project1` will continue to import the non-vendored `google.golang.org/grpc/...` packages.  While the vendored package might be a copy of the upstream, Go treats them as independent packages.  So the types they contain are not equivalent.

What has most likely happened is that one of your non-vendored dependencies imports the grpc package and uses its types in its public API.  When you make use of that API from `project1`, you get the upstream type which can't be assigned to variables using the vendored types.

There's two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Vendor all of your dependencies that make use of what you've already vendored.
2. If you're using Go >= 1.11, switch to the [newer Go module build system](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules).  This will let you continue to control when you upgrade your dependencies without having the `project1/vendor/...` tree to confuse the type system.